# Shimano 400 Rear Derailleur Reassembly

Tags: derailleur

I thought I was removing the rear derailleur so I could straighten the bent hangar but apparently I was disassembling it. Now I can't get the spring wound back around fully for reassembly.

Is there a trick for getting these back together or did I break it?

[image: partially disassembled shimano 400]

EDIT: is this the "b-plate?"
[image: b-plate?]

Answer (score 4):

Typically the derailleurs fixing bolt goes thru this area. If whatever sort of cover can be put back on securely, it's not broke. The ends of the spring have to rest within designated holes.  The outer side of the spring (pictured) may rest inside that groove. It's hard to tell the orientation of the end in the photo. If it doesn't sit in that slot, there should be a recess in the cover to secure the end of the spring.

The spring assembly will be put together with the spring at rest. In a more modern derailleur without the claw hangar, winding of the B-spring is accomplished by winding the B-plate (silver piece opposite the out-facing opening). The technique involves using an Allen key as a lever, the crook of the Allen key rests on the fixing bolt which acts as a fulcrum. The short side of the Allen wrench is fit between the B-Screw and bolt in such a way that pressure on the long aspect of the wrench will wind the B-plate assembly--which secures one end of the spring--and this in turn winds the spring (given both it's ends are captive in their spots).

So, I would suggest finding a way to secure one or the other of the B-plate assembly or the derailleur body and rotating whichever aspect is not captive.

Comment: If by "b-plate" you mean the part i was calling the hangar (see pic i added above), then that's exactly the problem. This part doesn't clear the derailleur body to rotate enough for the spring to engage.

Comment: It's all a moot point; the spring just broke. Guess I'll be riding with reduced gear range, recycling the bike or finding a cheap replacement rear derailleur for a 5 speed freewheel.  :-/

Comment: Thanks for your reply too! I almost forgot.